# Showing the category hierarchy as clicked in WordPress, with image and desc

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

have a very weared issue, i am sure the solution is simple but i am not very used to wordpress and cant figure this out.

what i have is a WordPress theme and if needed i can change it to any other docent mater.

**what i have is**

i have some category in my wordpress and they have child and the child has child it goes to 4 lavels.
like

```
Book
-Novel
--book name
---chapter 1
---chapter 2

Article 
-about life
--life article 1
--life article 2
```

etc etc this is just a simple example.

**Now What i want is**

> i want to show the list of main categories with its image and
>   description on the home page and when clicked on a category show its
>   child and when clicked on a child show its child on next page and so
>   on. at the end the final post.

also for category image i have added a plugin called category image in wordpress.

i have tried to show the list of categories on home page with the help of some plugin, like this `[categories]` this short code helps to show the list of categories but i also want to show the image, description and the hierarchy when clicked.

i will be really happy if any one can give me any advice, help or any suggestion. i am still working will post here for any progress. Thankx

**What i am looking for is**

> When clicked on fiction category open all the books in that category
>   and then when clicked on a book name open all the chapters and then
>   when clicked on a chapter open the post

[image]

> what i need is i think very simple, just a hierarchy of category when
>   clicked. like if i click on novel all the books in novel category
>   should open and then when i click on any book all the chapters of the
>   book should open and then clicked on chapter the post should open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use [Taxonomy Images](https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-images/) Plugin instead of your one to show images
2. Then, use the following [Link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/182812/create-a-category-list-page/182813) to display categories

And then, use the following code below to show your child categories...

```
<?php 
        $term_children = get_terms(
            'product-cat',
            array(
                'parent' => get_queried_object_id(),
                'hide_empty' => false,
            )
        );
       if (!empty($term_children)) { ?>
       <ul>
                <?php 
                    if ( ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
                        foreach ( $term_children as $child ) {
                            echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link( $child ).'">'.$child->name.'</a></li>';
                        }
                    }
                ?>
       </ul>
      <?php } ?>
```

Comment: i am sorry it dosent works, it gives me the same result where i am right now. just a list of my categories, i want when clicke on a category i want to show the sub category on the new page and then so on.

Comment: @TheRahulJha that is a working example. Many of my developed theme using the snippet. Make sure you installed the "Taxonomy Images" and then uninstall your previous one. **Note: The snippet is for a custom category type taxonomy, you use that for your one**

Comment: Also, you can upload your code here so that I can see.

Comment: http://www.reurl.in/bd6143348  here is the website you can check if you need admin panel i will send you the details too you can check all. what i need is i will mention clearly in question.

Comment: Go to this page here [link](https://clients.appatlantis.com/soldy/product-cat/electronics/). In this page, the Electronics category listing the products and aside from that the sub-categories are being shown. Please let me know that if you are looking for something like that. If so, I will send you the complete code of that.